# data is not defined reference error NodeJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, express

My code works fine if don't redirect my show.ejs file then this error doesn't show up but when I try to redirect it to places.ejs it shows this error I don't know where I'm going wrong please help me solve this issue.I'm attaching herewith my error log , a part of the index.js code and routes.js code Thank you

> error

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nt\views\show.ejs:38
    36|   <div class="card"  style="width: 18rem;">

    37| 

 >> 38|   <img src="http://localhost:3000/imgs/uploads/<%=data[0].images%>" class="card-img-top responsive" alt="...">

    39|   <div class="card-body">

    40|     <h5 class="card-title"><%=data[0].title%></h5>

    41|     <p class="card-text"><%=data[0].description%></p>


data is not defined
```

> part of my index.js code

```
app.get('/new', loginRequired, routes.new);
app.post('/', loginRequired, routes.new);
app.get('/show/:username', loginRequired, routes.show);
app.get('/places', loginRequired, routes.places);
```

> routes.js code:

```
const {
   con,
   sessionStore
 } = require('./config/db');
const { route } = require('./routes/auth');
exports.new = function(req, res){
    message = '';
   if(req.method == "POST"){
      const post  = req.body;
      const username= post.username;
      const title= post.title;
      const state= post.state;
      const category= post.category;
      const description= post.description;
 
      if (!req.files)
                return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
 
      const file = req.files.uploaded_image;
      var img_name=file.name;
 
         if(file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||file.mimetype == "image/png"||file.mimetype == "image/gif" ){
                                 
              file.mv('public/imgs/uploads/'+file.name, function(err) {
                             
               var sql = "INSERT INTO `nt_data`(`username`,`title`,`state`,`category`, `images` ,`description`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
               var query = con.query(sql, [username, title, state, category, img_name, description], function(err) {
                  console.log(err)
                 if (!err) {
                   res.redirect('show/' + username);
                 }
                 else {
                  message = "This format is not allowed , please upload file with '.png','.gif','.jpg'";
                  res.render('new.ejs',{message: message});
                }
               }); 
            }); 
          
   } 
}
   else {
      res.render('new');
   }
 
};

exports.show = function(req, res){
    let message = '';
    var username = req.params.username;
    const sql="SELECT * FROM `nt_data` WHERE `username`='"+username+"'"; 
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
       console.log(err)
      if(result.length <= 0){
      message = "show not found!";
      
      res.render('show.ejs',{data:result, message: message});
     }else{
      res.redirect('/places');
     }
   });
   res.render('show')
};
 
exports.places=function (req,res,result){
   let message = '';
   var username = req.params.username;
    const sql="SELECT * FROM `nt_data` WHERE `username`='"+username+"'"; 
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
       console.log(err)
       if(result.length <= 0)
       console.log(err)
         message = "places not found!";
   res.render('places.ejs',{data:result, message: message});
    });
}
```

Comment: while you redirection to `res.redirect('show/' + username);` you also need to pass data object. Everywhere you are rendering shown.ejs you need to pass the data object and if you don't want to pass the data just use an if condition in you ejs file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Page Redirecting issues Node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65183218/page-redirecting-issues-node-js)

Comment: @Arvind Rajput but I have defined data in exports.show will that not work?

Comment: @eol no I have changed the code

Comment: Delete the other question then, please.